# $f(t) = te^t + \int_0^t \tau f(t-\tau)d\tau$

Tags: laplace-transform, integro-differential-equations

How can I solve for $f(t)$ given $f(t) = te^t + \int_0^t \tau f(t-\tau)d\tau$

I began by taking the laplace transform of all the terms to get $$F(s) = \frac{1}{(s-1)^2} + \frac{F(s)}{s^2}$$ I am stuck on what to do when I solve for $$F(s) = \frac{1}{(s-1)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{s^2}}$$ Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As it stands your question is incoherent and the title provides no information as to what you are actually asking. If you are wanting to take the Laplace transform of the function in the title, _why don't you put the function in the body of your question_.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Edited for clarification

Comment: Hint: Make the fraction $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{s^2}}$ look nicer, then use the convolution property (as seen in the question I just answered for you - the table linked there should help).

Comment: @SeanRoberson D'OH. Thank you $\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}\cdot \frac{s^2}{s^2 - 1}$ That makes it much better

Comment: @SeanRoberson So I got it to $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}\cdot \frac{s^2}{s^2-1}\right\}$ but I'm not sure if I should treat this as $te^t \ast \cos t \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{s\}$

Comment: $$F(s)= \frac{s^2}{(s-1)^3 (s+1)}$$
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}[F(s)](t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{s^2}{(s-1)^3 (s+1)}\right](t)=\frac{1}{8} e^{-t} \left(e^{2 t} \left(2 t^2+6 t+1\right)-1\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe the use of the Laplace transform is quite unnecessary given that the process of finding the inverse image of it is most of the time quite annoying and time-consuming and you can easily avoid it. In particular, if you differentiate both sides of the given equation we achieve the following:
$$f^{'}(x)=(x+1)e^x+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt.$$
Repeating the same process we finally get
$$f^{''}(x)=(x+2)e^x+f(x)$$ or $$f^{''}(x)-f(x)=(x+2)e^x.$$
Thus, by setting $y=f(x)$ we obtain a 2nd-order non-homogeneous linear differential equation, in particular we have that
$$y^{''}-y=(x+2)e^x,$$ with the initial conditions being $y(0)=0$ and $y^{'}(0)=1$. Thus, using variation of parameters we see that
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{8}e^x(e^{-2x}(2x^2+6x+1)-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are still looking for an answer, but here is a perhaps longer but easier alternative approach, which makes use of series expansion instead of Laplace transform.

Firstly, let's recall that the solution can be Taylor expanded (around zero) as $f(t) = \displaystyle \sum_{n\ge0} f^{(n)}(0)\frac{t^n}{n!}$, where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n^\mathrm{th}$ derivative. It is easy to check by differentiating the original equation that the latter satisfies
$$
f^{(n)}(t) = te^t + \int_0^t \tau f^{(n)}(t-\tau) \,\mathrm{d}\tau + ne^t + tf^{(n-1)}(0) + f^{(n-2)}(0),
$$
hence the simple inhomogeneous first-order linear recurrence relation $f^{(n)}(0) = f^{(n-2)}(0) + n$, which is solved by $f^{(n)}(0) = A + B(-1)^n + \frac{1}{4}n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n - \frac{3}{8}$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants to be determined thanks to the the initial conditions $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$.

Finally, plugging this expression into the Taylor series will lead to a solution made of exponentials with polynomial prefactors, such as gpmath's inverse Laplace transform in the comment section.